# Endomorphism structure of the Klein four-group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I am reading the Algebra by Grillet, this is ex 17(-18), pag. 22.

I understand that $V$ can be viewed as a two dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{F}_2$. Noticed this, it is easy to see that $End(V)$ is the set of two by two matrices on such space.

My question is: is there a more direct way to see this? That is, without resorting to "other" kind of structures?

Comment: The endomorphisms of $\Bbb F_p^n$ are $n\times n$ matrices over $\Bbb F_p$. How would you even describe the matrix ring without reference to matrices? This **is** the direct way to see this. It's what the thing is.

Comment: I see your point. What I meant is to avoid seeing V as vector space. Do you see my point?

Comment: I don't see the point of trying to avoid regarding $V$ as a vector space.

Comment: If you are willing to allow more general/abstract results for "direct", you could use $\operatorname{Hom}(\bigoplus_{i\in I} G_i, \prod_{j \in J} G_j) \cong \prod_{i \in I} \prod_{j \in J} \operatorname{Hom}(G_i,G_j)$. Elements of the latter product are most conveniently written as formal matrices. Describing $\operatorname{Hom}(G_i,G_j)$ for two cyclic groups is easy (even more so in your special case where $G_i\cong G_j\cong \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$). This approach generalizes to arbitrary finitely generated abelian groups.

Comment: To emphasize earlier comments: All abelian groups *are* $\mathbb{Z}$-modules in a completely natural manner, and it is perfectly fair to study them using the theory of $\mathbb{Z}$-module. More to the point, all abelian 2-groups *are* vector spaces over $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ in a completely natural manner, and it is perfectly fair to study them using the theory of vector spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Well you could argue that if $x$ and $y$ are any two non-zero elements of the group, then any element can be written uniquely as $ax + by$ where $a, b \in \{0, 1\}$, moreover if $a, b, c, d \in \{0, 1\}$ there is a unique endomorphism such that $x \mapsto ax + by$ and $y \mapsto cx + dy$ (and conversely any endomorphism determines $a, b, c, d$ uniquely). So the endomorphisms are in one-to-one correspondence with matrices
$\left(\begin{array}{cc}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{array}\right)$ with $a, b, c, d \in \{0, 1\}$.

However, you will have to verify lots of little details and these details are just special cases of facts about vector spaces. So introducing the vector spaces saves you lots of work.